# Disabling Buttons after being clicked

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

Is there any way to disable the button once it is clicked?. We are facing a scenario in chatbot application development in Azure Bot (NodeJS) which requires Buttons to be disable once clicked, So user would not scroll back and try to click button which wouldn't give specified outcome

My JS code

```
var MyWebChat = function(params) {

    // Webchat client args
    var user = {
        id: params['userid'] || 'userid',
        name: params["username"] || 'username'
    };

    var bot = {
        id: params['botid'] || 'botid',
        name: params["botname"] || 'botname'
    };

    // Create Directline connection and application
    const  botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
        domain: params['domain'],
        token: document.getElementById("directLineToken").value,
        secret: params['s'],
        webSocket: params['webSocket'] && params['webSocket'] === "true" // defaults to true
    });

    BotChat.App({
        locale: params['locale'],
        resize: 'detect',
        speechOptions: speechOptions,
        user: user,
        botConnection: botConnection
    }, document.getElementById(params['targetElement']));

             botConnection.activity$.subscribe(function (activity) {
    $(".wc-message-wrapper[data-activity-id='" + activity.id + "'] .ac-pushButton").click(function () {
        console.log($(this));
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
});
    this.loadApplication = function() {
        /**
         * Sends custom parameter to the chatbot
         **/

        var sendCustomArg = function() {
            console.log('post message');
            botConnection
                .postActivity({
                    type: "event",
                    value: "loginPageValue",
                    from: {
                        id: "passwordResetID",
                        source: "loginPage"
                    },
                    name: "loginPage"
                })
                .subscribe(function(id) { console.log("YOUR CUSTOM ARG HAS BEEN SENT")});
        }

        sendCustomArg();

        /**
         * When window unloads send endOfConversation
         * This event is catched by the bot that can freeup server resources
         **/
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            botConnection
                .postActivity({
                    type: "endOfConversation",
                    from: {
                        id: params['userid']
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(function(id){ console.log("endOfConversation ack")});
        };
    };

    return this;
};
```

My HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- CSS -->
      <link href="https://XXXXX/QABotUI.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700|Roboto+Condensed:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://XXXXX/QASessionDemo.js"></script>

    <div id="chat-application">
       <!-- <span class="btn2" id="button2" style="float:right;right:5px;z-index: 6;position: relative;top:12px;"><svg height="16" viewBox="0 0 48 49" width="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m45.587 45.632c-2.132 2.135-3.731 3.469-5.863 1.334l-15.724-15.745-15.724 15.745c-2.132 2.135-3.731.534-5.863-1.334-2.133-1.868-3.465-3.736-1.333-5.871l15.724-15.745-15.724-15.745c-2.132-2.135-.533-4.003 1.333-5.871 1.865-1.868 3.731-3.469 5.863-1.334l15.724 15.745 15.724-15.745c2.132-2.135 3.731-.534 5.863 1.334 2.133 1.868 3.465 3.736 1.333 5.871l-15.724 15.745 15.724 15.745c2.132 2.135.8 4.003-1.333 5.871z" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg> </span> -->
       <div id="botChat" class="wc-narrow"></div>
   </div>

    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script src="https://XXXX/QABotChat.js"></script>
   <script>
        var webchatParams = {
            userid:'userid',
            username:'You',
            botid: 'XXXXXX',
            botname:'XXXXX',
            targetElement: 'botChat', // html element where the webchat gets rendered
            s:'XXXXXX',
            customArg: 'common'
        };
          new MyWebChat(webchatParams).loadApplication();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: On which channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the directline method for the bot webchat. Then you can subscribe to the activities and register a click handler on the buttons. You need to create the botConnection directline object and then register it to the app before subscribing to the activities.

```
const botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
        domain: params['domain'],
        token: document.getElementById("directLineToken").value,
        webSocket: params['webSocket'] && params['webSocket'] === 'true' // defaults to true
    });

BotChat.App({
    bot: bot,
    locale: params['locale'],
    resize: 'detect',
    speechOptions: speechOptions,
    user: user,
    botConnection: botConnection
}, document.getElementById('BotChatGoesHere'));
```

The following will disable the button that was pressed.

```
botConnection.activity$.subscribe(function (activity) {
    $(".wc-message-wrapper[data-activity-id='" + activity.id + "'] .ac-pushButton").click(function () {
        console.log($(this));
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
});
```

The following will disable all buttons in that message.

```
botConnection.activity$.subscribe(function (activity) {
    $(".wc-message-wrapper[data-activity-id='" + activity.id + "']").on("click", ".ac-pushButton", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".wc-message-wrapper[data-activity-id='" + activity.id + "'] .ac-pushButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
});
```

To hide the hover effect on disabled buttons, add the following to your css:

```
button[disabled] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: I don't have a public bot that has that registered right now. But you should be able to follow the tutorial for setting up directline and drop that in and it should work.

Comment: I dropped in this code in direct line But buttons are still clickable. I get this in console:  w.fn.init [button.ac-pushButton]
0
:
button.ac-pushButton
accessKey
:
""
assignedSlot
:
null
attributeStyleMap
:
StylePropertyMap {size: 7}
attributes
:
NamedNodeMap {0: type, 1: class, 2: disabled, 3: style, type: type, class: class, disabled: disabled, style: style, length: 4}
autocapitalize
:
""
autofocus
:
false
baseURI
.. Is there anything that should go inside app.js code in Azure bot?

Comment: Ive made changes in Direct line as below // Create Directline connection and application
    var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
        secret: params['s'],
        webSocket: params['webSocket'] && params['webSocket'] === "true" // defaults to true
    });
 botConnection.activity$.subscribe(function (activity) {
    $(".wc-message-wrapper[data-activity-id='" + activity.id + "'] .ac-pushButton").click(function () {
        console.log($(this));
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
})

Comment: I've edited my answer. You need to subscribe to the activities after inserting the web chat.

Comment: Some how it is not working with your code... Am i missing something?

Comment: I am unable to get expected result.. Updated my question with the code.. Please help me

Comment: What is your dialog code for sending the buttons from the bot?

Comment: I am using  builder.Prompts.choice(session,entityResp, session.conversationData.choiceEntitiesArray,{listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button});

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180543/discussion-between-vinay-jayaram-and-kjr1995).